# How to redirect user based on role to a specific web page?

Tags: php

I want to be able to redirect a user upon login to a web page based on their role assigned to them.   I can Register the user with a role in it saves to my database.  So in my database I have

```
------------------------------------------------
|id   | username | password | role | created_at|
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Admin    | *******  | Test | date      |
------------------------------------------------
```

And then in my login form I have:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to 
welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
header("location: welcome.php");
exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

// Check if username is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = "Please enter username.";
} else{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}

// Check if password is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

// Validate credentials
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, role, password FROM users WHERE username = ? and pasword = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_role, $param_password);

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_role     = $role;
        $param_password = $password;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $role, $hashed_password);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        // Password is correct, so start a new session
                        session_start();

                        // Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;   
                        $_SESSION["role"] = $role;

                        switch( $role ) {
                            case 'test':
                                        header("location:test.php");
                            exit();

                            case 'User':
                                        header("location:User.php");
                            exit();

                            case 'AnotherRole':
                                        header("location:AnotherRole.php");
                            exit();

                        }
                        // Redirect user to welcome page
                        header("location: welcome.php");
                    } else{
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }


                    }

            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
    .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" 
 method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has- 
 error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" 
 value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has- 
  error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
        </div>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>. 
 </p>
    </form>
 </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

And when I try to log in with test it doesn't redirect me the to test.php it just takes me back to the login.php page.

Not sure where I went wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the third parameter of [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function which is the status code. Use a temporary redirection code, in your case, a [`303 See Other`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) looks fine.